# Creating submenu with css in IE

Tags: css

I want to create sub-menus in IE using CSS, but IE does not work with hover action.  I don't want to use JavaScript.

How can I solve this?  Is there another way to create sub-menus without CSS or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for IE6 based on jQuery library

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie 6') > -1){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.menu li').hover(
            function() {
                jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
            },

            function() {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('hover');    
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Please change the selector ".menu li" to yours and wrote in CSS in the following way
.menu li:hover, .menu li.hover { ... }

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean IE does not work with hover action? IE6 and earlier only supports :hover on A tags and IE7 and later supports it on any tag. It is definitely possible to make 100% CSS menus. Here's what I found with a quick Google search.

http://www.surguy.net/menu/index.html

Comment: Also it applies :hover to non ATags

Answer (score 0):

IE6 and below supports the `:HOVER` pseudo-class on `<a>` tags only. You can make the `<a>` tag behave like a block level element (I assume you are currently using `<ol><li>`) by applying the following CSS:

```
a.submenu { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html), an HTC extension that enables the use of the :hover pseudo-class on all elements, not just anchors, in IE6.

Usage is simple. Add this to the header, changing the path to reflect your setup:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{behavior:url(path/to/iehover.htc);}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

That's it!

Comment: **@cpharmston:** Only works when JavaScript is enabled. An unobtrusive solution is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page but didn't have a chance to see if it was really CSS only. http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html

My original method seems to no longer work on most browsers and wouldn't validate.